# Can I install Microsoft Visual Studio on my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: installation, microsoft

I want to use SQL server R2 2008(which in on another server) by installing its client. Is their any way to sort out my problem. Please help

Comment: can you explain more precisely what you intend to do? in the caption you write that you want to install Visual Studio, then in the text you write that you want to use SQL server and later you write that you intend to use the client...? If you need an SQL server, use MySQL server instead or, if you need a commercial product, go for e.g. IBM DB2 which works on Linux natively. However, you could setup a virtual machine with Windows on your Ubuntu host and run whatever Microsoft product you want in there.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Visual Studio to access MS SQL Server. If you're developing an application (as mentioning Visual Studio would imply), you need some library for your language of choice which would allow you to connect to the server.

What is the language you're using?

For example, for Python there's [pymssql](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/)

There's also [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/), which, as I understand, is a set of command-line tools and libraries to connect to MSSQL and Sybase servers.

At any rate, I think it would be very difficult to install Visual Studio in Ubuntu (well, apart from installing it inside a VirtualBox instance running Windows).